# python: why does random.shuffle change the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shuffle

I'm using `random.shuffle` to shuffle a 2D `numpy` array. I met with the following problem:

```
import numpy as np
from random import shuffle as sf 

b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
print b
# [1 2 3 4 5]
sf(b)
print b
# [1 4 5 3 2]

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print a
# [[1 2 3]
#  [4 5 6]
#  [7 8 9]]
sf(a)
print a
# [[1 2 3]
#  [4 5 6]
#  [1 2 3]]
```

The result shows that when shuffling 1D array, everything is correct. But while shuffling 2D array, the result becomes strange.

Why is the third row of the original array thrown away and the first row duplicated by twice?

I know there could be solutions to solve this problem, such as firstly shuffle a 1D array indicating the row ids and then extract the 2D array in the order of the shuffled ids. But I do want to make clear what happens to the implementation of `random.shuffle`, or what's wrong with my code.

Comment: This has wasted a lot of my time, and it took me 1 week to find out that random.shuffle does not work in such cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shuffle from the `random` module isn’t made to deal with numpy arrays since it’s not exactly the same as nested python lists. You should use the [`numpy.random`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) module’s [`shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html#numpy.random.shuffle) instead.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import shuffle

arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
shuffle(arr)
print(arr)
# output:
# [[4 5 6]
# [1 2 3]
# [7 8 9]]
```